# Flex выравнивание элементов по левому краю с отступами

Tags: css, css3, flexbox

Есть такой код:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 370px;
  padding: 0 18px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container>div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 27px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Когда блоков `div` внутри контейнера число кратное трем, то все отражается отлично. Но если убрать один из блоков, то на последней строке блоки будут раскинуты по правой и левой стороне.

Так вот вопрос - как сделать так, чтобы в случае если блоков 5, то пятый блок располагался бы под вторым?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/cfnxzadc/

Comment: @soledar10 прикольно конечно, но программистам вы так и будете объяснять, что в цикле выводим все блоки, но без контента не заполняем?)) А если элементов всего 5?

Comment: Автор, зачем здесь флексы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мой вариант:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 370px;
  padding: 0 18px;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.container>div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 27px;
}
.container:after{
  content: '';
  flex: 0 1 100px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но правильно ли я понмаю что этот код будет работать только с 3-х колоночным макетом, а как его можно подправить для 4-х колоночного?

Comment: @ГеоргийТарасов https://codepen.io/Muzyka/pen/wrOJgb Вот набросал код немного универсальней.